# JAXB propOrder Title case tags not working

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

I need to maintain the tags order after marshaling using jaxb where xml tags are title case.
When trying to Marshal it throwing below error.

"Property applicationCountFromDate is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder"

Please find below full stack and code.

```
 
Property applicationCountFromDate is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean.getApplicationCountFromDate()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property applicationCountToDate is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean.getApplicationCountToDate()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property approvedApplicationCount is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean.getApprovedApplicationCount()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property declineApplicationCount is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean.getDeclineApplicationCount()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property displayName is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean.getDisplayName()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property operationErrorCode is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean.getOperationErrorCode()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property operationErrorMessage is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean.getOperationErrorMessage()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property operationStatus is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean.getOperationStatus()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property submittedApplicationCount is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean.getSubmittedApplicationCount()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property totalAppliationCount is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean.getTotalAppliationCount()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property OperationStatus appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant operationStatus?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property OperationErrorCode appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant operationErrorCode?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property OperationErrorMessage appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant operationErrorMessage?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property DisplayName appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant displayName?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property ApplicationCountFromDate appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant applicationCountFromDate?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property ApplicationCountToDate appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant applicationCountToDate?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property TotalAppliationCount appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant totalAppliationCount?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property ApprovedApplicationCount appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant approvedApplicationCount?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property SubmittedApplicationCount appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant submittedApplicationCount?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
Property DeclineApplicationCount appears in @XmlType.propOrder, but no such property exists. Maybe you meant declineApplicationCount?
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
```

Code :

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
@XmlType (propOrder = {  "operationStatus",
        "operationErrorCode",
        "operationErrorMessage",
        "JSessionID",
        "DSACode",
        "displayName",
        "applicationCountToDate",
        "totalAppliationCount",
        "approvedApplicationCount",
        "submittedApplicationCount",
        "declineApplicationCount"
    })

public class LoginRESBean
{
    private String ApplicationCountToDate;

    private String TotalAppliationCount;

    private String ApplicationCountFromDate;

    private String DeclineApplicationCount;

    private String DSACode;

    private String SubmittedApplicationCount;

    private String ApprovedApplicationCount;

    private String DisplayName;

    private String OperationErrorMessage;

    private String OperationStatus;

    private String OperationErrorCode;

    private String JSessionID;

    @XmlElement (name = "ApplicationCountToDate")
    public String getApplicationCountToDate ()
    {
        return ApplicationCountToDate;
    }
    public void setApplicationCountToDate (String ApplicationCountToDate)
    {
        this.ApplicationCountToDate = ApplicationCountToDate;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "TotalAppliationCount")
    public String getTotalAppliationCount ()
    {
        return TotalAppliationCount;
    }

    public void setTotalAppliationCount (String TotalAppliationCount)
    {
        this.TotalAppliationCount = TotalAppliationCount;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "ApplicationCountFromDate")
    public String getApplicationCountFromDate ()
    {
        return ApplicationCountFromDate;
    }


    public void setApplicationCountFromDate (String ApplicationCountFromDate)
    {
        this.ApplicationCountFromDate = ApplicationCountFromDate;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "DeclineApplicationCount")
    public String getDeclineApplicationCount ()
    {
        return DeclineApplicationCount;
    }


    public void setDeclineApplicationCount (String DeclineApplicationCount)
    {
        this.DeclineApplicationCount = DeclineApplicationCount;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "DSACode")
    public String getDSACode ()
    {
        return DSACode;
    }

    public void setDSACode (String DSACode)
    {
        this.DSACode = DSACode;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "SubmittedApplicationCount")
    public String getSubmittedApplicationCount ()
    {
        return SubmittedApplicationCount;
    }

    public void setSubmittedApplicationCount (String SubmittedApplicationCount)
    {
        this.SubmittedApplicationCount = SubmittedApplicationCount;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "ApprovedApplicationCount")
    public String getApprovedApplicationCount ()
    {
        return ApprovedApplicationCount;
    }

    public void setApprovedApplicationCount (String ApprovedApplicationCount)
    {
        this.ApprovedApplicationCount = ApprovedApplicationCount;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "DisplayName")
    public String getDisplayName ()
    {
        return DisplayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName (String DisplayName)
    {
        this.DisplayName = DisplayName;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "OperationErrorMessage")
    public String getOperationErrorMessage ()
    {
        return OperationErrorMessage;
    }

    public void setOperationErrorMessage (String OperationErrorMessage)
    {
        this.OperationErrorMessage = OperationErrorMessage;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "OperationStatus")
    public String getOperationStatus ()
    {
        return OperationStatus;
    }

    public void setOperationStatus (String OperationStatus)
    {
        this.OperationStatus = OperationStatus;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "OperationErrorCode")
    public String getOperationErrorCode ()
    {
        return OperationErrorCode;
    }

    public void setOperationErrorCode (String OperationErrorCode)
    {
        this.OperationErrorCode = OperationErrorCode;
    }

    @XmlElement (name = "JSessionID")
    public String getJSessionID ()
    {
        return JSessionID;
    }

    public void setJSessionID (String JSessionID)
    {
        this.JSessionID = JSessionID;
    }
}
```

Comment: XML is case sensitive, so e.g. `<applicationCountFromDate>` is not the same as `<ApplicationCountFromDate>`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer to the Original Version of the Question

JAXB considers the method `getApplicationCountToDate()` to correspond to the property `applicationCountToDate` (note it starts with a lower case letter), so it is expecting `applicationCountToDate` in the `propOrder` not `ApplicationCountToDate`.  You get a pretty good exception in this case pointing you in the right direction.

```
Property applicationCountToDate is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean.getApplicationCountToDate()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean
        at public com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginRESBean com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean.getRS()
        at com.snapwork.bean.login.LoginMBBean
```

I have written more about `propOrder` on my blog:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/02/jaxbs-xmltype-and-proporder.html

---

### UPDATE

With your updated model, you should be getting the following exception:

```
Property applicationCountFromDate is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at public java.lang.String forum27147537.LoginRESBean.getApplicationCountFromDate()
        at forum27147537.LoginRESBean
```

The only thing I needed to do to the updated code in your question was add `applicationCountFromDate` to the `propOrder` to get everything working:

```
@XmlType (propOrder = {"operationStatus",
        "operationErrorCode",
        "operationErrorMessage",
        "JSessionID",
        "DSACode",
        "displayName",
        "applicationCountToDate",
        "applicationCountFromDate",
        "totalAppliationCount",
        "approvedApplicationCount",
        "submittedApplicationCount",
        "declineApplicationCount"
})

public class LoginRESBean
```

Comment: I tried using "applicationCountToDate" error change to "Property applicationCountFromDate is present but not specified in @XmlType.propOrder"

Comment: @AmitK - Can you update your question with the new `poprOrder` you are trying?

Comment: updated the question.I also gone through your blog..but unable to resolve my issue..

Comment: @AmitK - Can you post the new exception you are getting?

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan Thanks for updating your answer. Update part is working in my case. `propOrder` code is nice. +1.

Answer (score 1):

Property names are derived here from getter/setter names, not from field names.

So you'll have to write `operationStatus`, not `OperationStatus`.

I am not 100% it is always the case, maybe this depends on whether you annotate the the getter or the field itself.

Comment: Could please address what exactly i need to change in code

Comment: @AmitK Start by changing first letters to lowercase.